# How to Download Image through AJAX Request In ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Here is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public FileResult Download(TrainingModel pass)
{
    return File(pass.filePath, "image\jpg", "haha.jpg");
}
```

And here is my AJAX:

```
function fncDownloadImage(fileName)
{
    //passes the fileName the parameter to the Model
    var download = {'filePath' : fileName}
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Capability/Download',
        data: JSON.stringify(download),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (response) {
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
}
```

How to download the file with the above code? When I checked the `Network` tab on `Developer Tools` the image is present on the `Preview`.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX(Asynchronous JavaScript and XML) is asynchronous, to download any file from server, the request must be synchronous, ajax does not supports file downloads

for work around visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9970672/9641914), this will give "Ajax like" experience with file downloads